# PyMongo re search produces `InvalidDocument: Cannot encode object: regex.Regex('RT', flags=regex.V0)`

Tags: regex, python-2.7, pymongo

When I run the following code:

```
import pymongo
dbClient = pymongo.MongoClient()
db = dbClient["tweets"]

import regex as re
db["tweets"].find_one( {"text": re.compile('RT')} )
```

I get an exception:

```
InvalidDocument: Cannot encode object: regex.Regex('RT', flags=regex.V0)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `pymongo` doesn't know what to do with objects from the [`regex` module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex). When I import the native `re` module, compiled regular expressions are accepted as expected.